# How to change the value of cdlatex-math-modify-prefix?

Tags: latex, cdlatex

The prefix key used for creating common LaTeX commands in CDLaTeX is not changed after modifying the `cdlatex-math-modify-prefix` variable. I have tried changing it using `(setq cdlatex-math-modify-prefix ?/)` (as per the [documentation](https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex) and [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73180)) and using Emacs' customisation menu.

The **value of the variable itself is changed, but it does not take effect**. For instance, typing `/i` should then expand into `\textit{}`, but it doesn't — whereas typing `'i` still does (note, **`'`** is the default prefix).

Is it possible to change the prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the prefix key is mapped during the loading of the `cdlatex` package and all subsequent changes to the variable do not update the keymap. Therefore, **the `cdlatex-math-modify-prefix` variable should be set before loading the package**. With `use-package` you can achieve this as follows:

```
(use-package cdlatex
  :custom (cdlatex-math-modify-prefix ?/))
```